# Why can't I access a local file from my public ip address if I can from my private ip address?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip

I'm able to open the website being served on port 4568 on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and my private ip address, but I can't seem to do so on my public ip address. I've tried to access the website by typing :4568 after my public ip like I did for my localhost and private ip.

Is it possible to open a site running locally on my computer through my public IP? If so, how? If not, why not?

NOTE: I'm not exactly clear what tags are appropriate. Feel free to add or remove any you deem inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are likly behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). What this means is that your public IP address and private IP address are not necessarily mapped to each other fully. To explicitly map your application to your public address, try the following:

1. Go to your modems management page
2. Look for a 'Port Forwarding' tab (might be under an advanced or
   router menu)
3. There will probably be two or three field to enter:
4. The port on the public ip address to forward traffic from
5. The IP address to forward traffic to (your private IP)
6. (might be there) The port to send it to on the private IP

Assuming this works, all traffic going to your public IP address on that port will now go to your private IP address.

*WARNING* This is a simple rule and everyone on the internet can now access that port

Also make sure your web server is listening on `0.0.0.0` (all IP addresses) and your local firewall is allowing remote connections on the port in question.